# Elasticsearch Primary/Secondary cluster in case of Disaster recovery

Tags: elasticsearch

We have 2 datacenters where we have deployed 2 elasticsearch clusters and they are configured to use CCR (Cross Cluster Replication) in order to sync each-other.

Unfortunatelly CCR requires a License which we are not going to renew. There for we were thinking to convert the existing archiecture with CCR in a Primary/Secondary:

1. Applications connect to the Primary ELK cluster
2. In case of Disaster Recovery (e.g. Datacenter 1 goes down) we configure the applications to use the secondary ELK cluster located in the DC 2
3. Once the DC 1 is up and running again, the ELK cluster on DC 1 become the new secondary

Is this a valid approach? Is it achievable?

any tutorial on how to configure the PRimary/Seconday clusters in ELK
or "creating a recurrent backup of ELK1 and restore it on ELK2" is the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved this creating a primary/secondary Elasticsearch instance and we forwards the events with Logastash to both cluster at the same time

Comment: this is what we did as well